# Angular subobject Object is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, lint

I have an object returned from an api, and this object had a sub-object.
When I show the property from this sub object in my component html, he works.
But when I try building my project, I get the following error:

> Object is possibly 'undefined'.

My html component code:

```
<img [src]="person?.gallery?.images[0]?.url" />
```

I also try the code below, but now working and is complicated:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="person !== undefined && person.gallery !== undefined && person.gallery.images !== undefined && person.gallery.length > 0 && person.gallery.images[0] !== undefined">
        <img [src]="person?.gallery?.images[0]?.url" />
</ng-container>
```

In localhost works, but when I execute ng build –prod, I get these errors.

Comment: maybe it needs `person?.gallery?.images?.[0]?.url` - extra null protection on `images`. Not sure - it's hard to figure out which object it's referring to.

Comment: The above do not work on angular template. Also I see that you do this `person.gallery.images[0] !== undefined` on your second test so It might be another line. If you remove completely `<img [src]="person?.gallery?.images[0]?.url" />` does it still show an error ?

Answer (score 0):

Development and production modes in Angular are different. Depending on the setup you use in your project, the production mode might do additional checks.

In your case, try to use:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="person?.gallery?.images[0]?.url as u">
  <img [src]="u" />
</ng-container>
```

I would also suggest to reconsider your tactics. The `foo?.bar?.baz?.goo` construct looks like it could use a batter implementation.